# Esta return, can I reset the "clock" by visiting the Bahamas?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens

I've read a few questions/responses on this but seem to be reading conflicting information 
I've tried to find a number for immigration at Fort Lauderdale but don't appear to be able to call

My status is this I am a British citizen here on an esta which expires 1st April

I have a friend arriving for 2weeks 31 March and I would like to stay and spend time with her for 2 weeks

My intention was to fly to the abaco islands of the Bahamas for 3/4 nights then return to Florida and fly back to England with them on the 12th April

Hoping that my visit to the Bahamas would reset my 90 days even though il only be staying another week in the states before returning to my place of residence in the UK

Is this false hope/information tahrs going to get me in bother ? Would really appreciate some advice ?

Melanie

Answer (score 7):

**No**, a visit to the Bahamas is not going to "reset the clock", since they're included in the [Adjacent Islands zone](http://canberra.usembassy.gov/vwp/mexico_canada.html):

> Anguilla, Antigua, Aruba, **Bahamas**, Barbados, Barbuda, Bermuda,
>   Bonaire, British Virgin Islands, Cayman Islands, Cuba, Curacao,
>   Dominica, Dominican Republic, Grenada, Guadeloupe,  Haiti, Jamaica,
>   Marie-Galante, Martinique, Miquelon, Montserrat, Saba,
>   Saint-Barthelemy, Saint Christopher, Saint Eustatius, Saint
>   Kitts-Nevis, Saint Lucia, Saint Maarten, Saint Martin, Saint Pierre,
>   Saint Vincent, Grenadines, Trinidad, Tobago, Turks and Caicos Islands,
>   Other British, French and Netherlands territory or possessions
>   bordering on the Caribbean Sea.

So you'd need to go to Central or South America instead. Try Costa Rica?

Also, the 90-day rule is for entries under the [Visa Waiver Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Waiver_Program) (VWP).  [ESTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_System_for_Travel_Authorization) is just the preclearance that lets you fly to the US.  See [this answer to a similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22864/have-i-invalidated-my-own-esta-and-if-i-fly-to-mexico-does-that-mean-i-will-not/22869#22869) for a more detailed explanation.