# Does flying to Panama from the US reset the ESTA time counter?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, panama

I am travelling from Panama to Los Angeles and around the States for approx 80 days then flying back to Panama and making my way up Central America for approx 3 months before flying back to LA to fly home to Australia.

Will this be OK with an ESTA?

Does it count as spending too long in the States?

I have been told that Panama is not far enough away.

Comment: Not far enough for what ? I'm not sure I understand, the ESTA gives you 90 days so that covers your trip. Is your stop in LA on the way back just a stopover or a longer stay in the US ?

Comment: Just a stop over, we will need to fly into LA from Mexico and then will fly out of LA home. Might be there for a night or 2. I was told that we had to go to South America so that our visa would still be valid to fly back into LA.

Comment: While we are travelling in Mexico does that count towards the 90 days? It'll be after 2 months of travelling up central America.

Comment: possible duplicate of [90 Day rule on the US Visa Waiver Program not expiring if you go to Canada](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/90-day-rule-on-the-us-visa-waiver-program-not-expiring-if-you-go-to-canada)

Comment: Going to Panama is far enough away to stop the 90 day count.

Comment: Travel days only count towards the ESTA when you're in the US. It doesn't matter where you've been, if you come to the US and you haven't used up the 90d you should be fine

Comment: @Blackbird57 No it doesn't.  Going to Mexico or Canada or Caribbean islands and coming back to the US doesn't stop the 90 day count

Comment: Thanks for your help. So it's fine to leave the states and go to Panama and then make our way up central stopping in Mexico and Cuba before re entering the states to fly home? And our time In Mexico or Cuba won't count towards our 90days? Thanks for your help. Just want to make sure.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion but @Karlson is right, time in Mexico will count towards the ESTA

Comment: @Emily it will depend how you will leave and re enter the US.

Comment: We will be flying out and flying in to the states

Comment: I believe this is an edge case that will (almost wholly) depend on the whims of a border officer. The origins of the Canada/Mexico/Carribean was designed to stop border hopping resets and gaming the system. If the OP flies out of the US all the way to Panama that should stop the timer. The user then states that she will "make her way up" through Central America back to the US. One can assume this is by driving, but even if it is not, Panama is several countries beyond Mexico, so she _should be fine_. However, one never knows the vagaries of US CBP...

Comment: As far as the Vote to Close by reason of duplicate. This is NOT a duplicate. She is neither going to Canada, Mexico, or the Caribbean.

Answer (score 2):

According to the rules set forth under the [VWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Waiver_Program), you're allowed 90 days in the US, and visiting adjacent countries doesn't reset it.  The VWP zone includes [the US, Canada, Mexico and adjacent islands](http://canberra.usembassy.gov/vwp/mexico_canada.html).

Fortunately for you, Panama is NOT part of the VWP zone, and therefore you're fully entitled to visit Panama, have your VWP time period reset, and later return to the US.  However, you are still subject to any questions the CBP may have, and returning to the US sometimes results in a few extra questions.  If your itinerary is all prepared and you can show your plans, however, you'll be fine (I've done this too - although not to Panama, I went to Cuba).

[See a similar question on the Bahamas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43413/esta-return-can-i-reset-the-clock-by-visiting-the-bahamas?rq=1).