# Can I re enter the US on the VWP immediately after 90 days?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I have read conflicting information and can't seem to find the right number online to call.

I am a UK citizen visiting the US on an ESTA due to expire on 2nd April.
I would like to stay until the 12th as I have a friend coming out to visit.

If I fly to the Bahamas, Abaco Islands for 4 nights say on the 31st March to return to Florida around the 2nd April will that reset my ESTA and allow me to stay essentially for another 90 days although I actually only want another 9?

Comment: Does your 2 year ESTA expire on the 2nd of April, or is it the "until" on your US entry stamp that's the 2nd of April?

Comment: it will be until - this is my first esta since like 2011 so this is my first trip on it - I applied for it in December.

Comment: sorry such as? I can scan in my info? some one ha just told me its a no anyway because the Bahamas is an adjacent island..?

Comment: @MelanieM There are questions about the 90 day reset on this site.  Canada, Mexico and Caribbean Islands don't reset the 90 days.

Comment: Thank you Karlson. I thought that but the Bahamas is independently owned and elsewhere I had read that because of that it would work out fine that way.

Comment: @MelanieM You still seem to be confused about ESTA vs VWP, please see this answer for an explanation: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22864/have-i-invalidated-my-own-esta-and-if-i-fly-to-mexico-does-that-mean-i-will-not/22869#22869

Comment: ESTA is only for entry. It has nothing to do with stay, and cannot be "reset"; you get another ESTA when you need to enter the U.S. again after your ESTA expires.

Comment: Hello all - thanks so much for your advice and feedback.... so If I now understand rightly the ESTA is valid for 2 years - it permits travel to the US under the Visa Waiver - and I can spend 90 days in the US at a time to a maximum of 180 days in one calendar year. What I wanted to do was leave and come back.... spend a few more weeks but it seems flying to the Bahamas is not an option and I will literally have to go back to R=England for a few weeks then re enter the states?